# Libre office writer automatically closing

Tags: libreoffice

```
$ libreoffice --writer 
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 175: exec: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: not found
```

LibreOffice Writer is not opening on my Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the correct version of Ubuntu. You can get it form `lsb_release -a`. Also, run `libreoffice` from terminal and post the output.

Comment: @Raphael , Ubuntu version 16.04 , this the message from terminal **/usr/bin/libreoffice: 175: exec: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: not found**

Comment: ** libreoffice --writer /usr/bin/libreoffice: 175: exec: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: not found **

Comment: What are the results of running the command: `sudo apt install libreoffice-dbg && libreoffice --writer &` ?

Comment: So it won't get closed incorrectly only closed the usual way which will prevent corrupting or changing the user's default empty document that LibreOffice Writer opens with by default. Also voted to reopen this because it is not unclear anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall `libreoffice-core`.

The error message when you ran `libreoffice --writer` in a terminal revealed that `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash` is missing. That `oosplash` executable is [provided by the `libreoffice-core` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=oosplash&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any). Reinstalling this package should replace the missing file and possibly other missing or damaged files.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt --reinstall install libreoffice-core
```

If that is all that is broken, then this should fix it entirely.

<sub>(If not, running `libreoffice --writer` again may give another error, which should help you troubleshoot further.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

there's an error in the last command, it should be:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install --reinstall  libreoffice-core`

Comment: `sudo apt --reinstall install libreoffice-core` is also OK.

Answer (score 0):

(Fast forward...)

In Ubuntu 21.04: If something in /usr/lib/libreoffice/ has been corrupted or accidentally removed, packages other than libreoffice & libreoffice-core may need to be re-installed (there are a lot of them).   The following worked for me to recover from manually removing /usr/lib/libreoffice :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall liblibreoffice-java libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-report-builder libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-script-provider-bsh libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-sdbc-mysql libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoloader-java python3-uno uno-libs-private ure ure-java
```